# XSLT Transformation IBM JDK 1.7

Tags: java, xslt, transformation

I am struggling with an error:

> XL TXE-J exception while compiling: [ERR 0601] The expression
>   'xsl:with-param classname=class com.ibm.xtq.ast.nodes.WithParam' is
>   not supported. [ERR 0601] The expression 'xsl:with-param
>   classname=class com.ibm.xtq.ast.nodes.WithParam' is not supported.

We are migrating from IBM JDK 1.5 to 1.7. I have debugged further, IBM JDK 1.5 TransformerFactory  use `org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl` implementation , however 1.7 TransformerFactory use IBM own impl class. i.e: `com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.compiler.TransformerFactoryImpl`

Is the new Implementation does not supports with-param ?

Below is the full stack trace:

> XL TXE-J exception while compiling: [ERR 0601] The expression
>   'xsl:with-param classname=class com.ibm.xtq.ast.nodes.WithParam' is
>   not supported. [ERR 0601] The expression 'xsl:with-param
>   classname=class com.ibm.xtq.ast.nodes.WithParam' is not supported.    at
>   com.ibm.xtq.xslt.translator.v1.RTFTranslator.compileNodeRaw(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.ibm.xtq.xslt.translator.v1.RTFTranslator.compileNodes(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.ibm.xtq.xslt.translator.v1.RTFTranslator.compileNodes(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.ibm.xtq.xslt.translator.v1.RTFTranslator.compileChoose(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.ibm.xtq.xslt.translator.v1.RTFTranslator.compileNodeRaw(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.ibm.xtq.xslt.translator.v1.RTFTranslator.compileNodes(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.ibm.xtq.xslt.translator.v1.RTFTranslator.compileNodes(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.ibm.xtq.xslt.translator.v1.RTFTranslator.compileVariable(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.ibm.xtq.xslt.translator.v1.RTFTranslator.compileNodes(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.ibm.xtq.xslt.translator.v1.RTFTranslator.compileNodes(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.ibm.xtq.xslt.translator.v1.RTFTranslator.compileDirElemConstructor(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.ibm.xtq.xslt.translator.v1.RTFTranslator.compileNodeRaw(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.ibm.xtq.xslt.translator.v1.RTFTranslator.compileNodes(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.ibm.xtq.xslt.translator.v1.RTFTranslator.compileNodes(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.ibm.xtq.xslt.translator.v1.RTFTranslator.compileDirElemConstructor(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.ibm.xtq.xslt.translator.v1.RTFTranslator.compileNodeRaw(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.ibm.xtq.xslt.translator.v1.RTFTranslator.compileNodes(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.ibm.xtq.xslt.translator.v1.RTFTranslator.compileNodes(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.ibm.xtq.xslt.translator.v1.RTFTranslator.compileDirElemConstructor(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.ibm.xtq.xslt.translator.v1.RTFTranslator.compileNodeRaw(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.ibm.xtq.xslt.translator.v1.RTFTranslator.compileNodes(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.ibm.xtq.xslt.translator.v1.RTFTranslator.compileNodes(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.ibm.xtq.xslt.translator.v1.RTFTranslator.compileDirElemConstructor(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.ibm.xtq.xslt.translator.v1.RTFTranslator.compileNodeRaw(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.ibm.xtq.xslt.translator.v1.RTFTranslator.compileNodes(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.ibm.xtq.xslt.translator.v1.RTFTranslator.compileNodes(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.ibm.xtq.xslt.translator.v1.XSLTTranslator.compileTemplateIntoFunction(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.ibm.xtq.xslt.translator.v1.XSLTTranslator.compileTemplate(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.ibm.xtq.xslt.translator.Mode.compileNamedTemplate(Unknown Source)
>     at com.ibm.xtq.xslt.translator.Mode.compileTemplates(Unknown Source)
>     at com.ibm.xtq.xslt.translator.Mode.compileApplyTemplates(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.ibm.xtq.xslt.translator.StylesheetHelper.compileModes(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.ibm.xtq.xslt.translator.v1.XSLTTranslator.visitTree(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.ibm.xtq.xslt.drivers.XSLTCompiler.translate(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.ibm.xtq.xslt.drivers.XSLTCompiler.compile(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.compiler.TransformerFactoryImpl.createTemplates(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.AbstractTransformerFactory.newTransformer(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.AbstractTransformerFactory.newTransformerHandler(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.addStylesheet(JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.java:137)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.addStylesheet(JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.java:128)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.PipelineDefinition.addStyleSheet(PipelineDefinition.java:161)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.PipelineDefinition.configure(PipelineDefinition.java:152)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.Main.main(Main.java:72)
>   05:51:08,236 ERROR [main] JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker  - [ERR 0601] The
>   expression 'xsl:with-param classname=class
>   com.ibm.xtq.ast.nodes.WithParam' is not supported.

Regards,
Kishor

Comment: At least show the line of the transformation stylesheet which contains the offending `xsl:with-param` element.

Comment: PLease see code snippet below:

Comment: <xsl:variable name="isAMLCardresult">
   <xsl:call-template name="isAMLCard">
    <xsl:with-param name="ctry_prod_lower_case" select="$ctry_prod_lower_case"/>
   </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:variable>
  
 <xsl:variable name="isCANBTCardresult">
       <xsl:call-template name="isCANBTCard">
      <xsl:with-param name="ctry_prod_lower_case" select="$ctry_prod_lower_case"/>
     </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:variable>

Answer (score 0):

I have experience the same issue. 
I find out that I have put extra with-param clause outside of a 
call-template which I didn't intend to use the param-value for that template. 
By removing the with-param, the error goes away.

```
Following is code causing the problem:

    <xsl:call-template name="printNodeNameValues" />                            
    <xsl:with-param name="indentFlag" select="'true'"/> <--this code cause issue

<xsl:template name="printNodeNameValues">       
    <xsl:param name="indentFlag"/>
    <xsl:param name="count" />  
    <xsl:variable name="columnWidth" select="$count*3" />

    <fo:table>      
        <xsl:if test="$indentFlag = 'true'">
            <fo:table-column column-width="{$columnWidth}mm"/>
            <fo:table-column column-width="68mm"/>
            <fo:table-column column-width="80mm"/>
        </xsl:if>   
        <fo:table-body>
            <fo:table-row>          
                <xsl:if test="$indentFlag = 'true'">    
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block/>
                    </fo:table-cell>    
                </xsl:if>   

                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:call-template name="FormatString">
                                <xsl:with-param name="strToBeBroken" select="."/>
                                <xsl:with-param name="breakLength" select="31"/>
                                <xsl:with-param name="seperator_Start" select="'&lt;fo:block&gt;'"/>
                                <xsl:with-param name="seperator_End" select="'&lt;/fo:block&gt;'"/>         
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
        </fo:table-body>
    </fo:table>         

</xsl:template>
```